# ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index - json_normalize

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm using the below code to parse a json response to a pandas dataframe and then convert the nested json 'terms'

**Sample json:**

```
{
"conditions": [
    {
      "id": 3855792,
      "type": "apm_app_metric",
      "name": "Error percentage (2.5%)",
      "enabled": true,
      "entities": [
        "3418936",
        "39720385",
        "70369692",
        "3242026",
        "3744556",
        "5673838"
      ],
      "metric": "error_percentage",
      "condition_scope": "application",
      "terms": [
        {
          "duration": "5",
          "operator": "above",
          "priority": "critical",
          "threshold": "2.5",
          "time_function": "any"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Code:**

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd,os
from pandas.io.json.normalize import json_normalize

json_data = json.loads(response.text)
terms_data = json_normalize(data = json_data['conditions'], 
                            record_path = 'terms',
                            meta = ['condition_scope', 'enabled', 'id', 'metric', 'name', 'type', 'entities'])
```

However, the script is failing while trying to parse 'entities' into the dataframe with the below error

```
    meta = ['condition_scope', 'enabled', 'id', 'metric', 'name', 'type', 'entities'])
  File "C:\Users\M1049639\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\normalize.py", line 279, in json_normalize
    result[k] = np.array(v).repeat(lengths)
  File "C:\Users\M1049639\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3119, in __setitem__
    self._set_item(key, value)
  File "C:\Users\M1049639\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3194, in _set_item
    value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
  File "C:\Users\M1049639\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3391, in _sanitize_column
    value = _sanitize_index(value, self.index, copy=False)
  File "C:\Users\M1049639\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4001, in _sanitize_index
    raise ValueError('Length of values does not match length of ' 'index')
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Desired output:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Q4oI.png)

Final output: 
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQ3ri.png)

Comment: Side note: don't use `json.loads(response.text)`, use `response.json()`. The latter uses JSON-specific encoding handling of response data.

Comment: You can't pull in a whole list as a single meta column in a dataframe, no; how did you hope the output dataframe would look like?

Comment: I was hoping to have the entities column having all the values as a list and then splitting the dataframe into multiple rows depending on the number of values in entities. The final output should be something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQ3ri.png

Comment: That's not something that `json_normalize` can do for you. You'll have to write additional code to duplicate the rows and add in the `entities` column.

Comment: I have a function whose input will be a dataframe with all the columns and the entities column will be a list object containing all values. A new dataframe will be created with duplicated rows and adding the  entities column individually. The problem lies in getting a dataframe with the entities column having the list object. Can you help in getting the output dataframe like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Q4oI.png Or perhaps suggest a better way this can be achieved?